# rxbag timeline and plots incorrect

Tags: ros, rxbag, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried rxbag with the bag at:
pr.willowgarage.com/data/gmapping/basic_localization_stage.bag.

The result is in screenshot:
alunos.deec.uc.pt/~a2004110783/rxbag.png

The base_scan topic only shows messages up to 0:08, while there are more, just like tf.
On the plot the translation.y is not getting plotted an instead it is a straight line at y=0.

This is in Fuerte with all the apt-get updates.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51055/rxbag-timeline-and-plots-incorrect/) by [nunojpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/3842/nunojpg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Beside rxbag also the new replacement rqt_bag shows the same effect.

The bag file contains one message (at about 0:08) which timestamp is not in-order. You can fix the bag file by calling `bagsort YOUR-BAG.bag YOUR-FIXED-BAG.bag`.

Unfortunately that bagsort script is currently broken. I already committed a patch - if you don't want to wait for the new release you can just apply the simple fix from https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/42 manually.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2012-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2